# О безударных гласных

Tags: орфография

Давно мучает вопрос о проверяемых безударных гласных  в корне слова. В нем столько исключений, что уже само правило кажется исключением. Не буду о корнях с чередованием, где всё понятно (-лаг- - -лож-, -бер- - -бир-...). Но вот почему сИдит, если сЕл; вИсит, если повЕсили? И таких примеров можно ещё привести немало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приведенные Вами корни не проверяются ударением. так как это тоже чередующиеся корни. Проверять их ударением нельзя! ТАм есть свои закономерности, менее четкие, чем для других корней, может быть, поэтому о них отдельно не говорится в курсе орфографии. Тем не менее в "Правилах русской орфографии" (Академическое издание под ред. Лопатина) они сформулированы. Например, в корнях сид-сед буква И пишется перед мягким Д (сидеть, сидя), , буква Е  перед твердым Д (седло), а также  - перед мягким Д -  в словах, производных от слова седло.

Answer (score 1):

*С**и**дит*, потому что *с**и**дя*. Глагол *сидеть* (корень -сид-) и глагол *сесть* (корень -сес-) в современном русском языке относятся к разным словообразовательным гнездам (словарь Тихонова). Этимологически (в диахронии) слова имеют общее происхождение от праслав. формы *sěsti. Но, повторяю, в **современном** русском языке глаголы **сидеть** и **сесть** имеют разные корни. Поэтому проверять глагол **сидит** глаголом **cел** неправильно.

То же относится и к глаголу *в**и**сит (в**и**сеть)*, который проверяется словом *в**и**снуть*, в не словом *пов**е**сили*. Эти глаголы тоже имеют общее происхождение от от праслав. формы *visěti. Но в современном языке относятся к разным словообразовательным гнездам. В глаголе висеть (висит) корень -вис-, а в глаголе повесили корень -вес-.

Общее правило таково: даже если слова имеют общее происхождение, проверять правописание в корне можно только исходя из современного состояния языка.